# Import Error: no module named bplanner.app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I' m trying to run my docker containers ( Flask app) but i got an error that says:
Import error no module named bplanner.app

**Docker compose :**

[image]

**Error :**
[image]

**Dockerfile :**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FuwX.jpg]

Comment: Editing is required in showing image.

Comment: I can't run those PNG files to try reproducing this.  Can you replace them with the actual text of the files in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> bplanner.app:create_app()
> ```

You're calling a python method from within a gunicorn command.  I don't think that's possible.  Instead create a separate python file which imports the `create_app` function and makes the resulting app object available to gunicorn.

You haven't posted any python code, or a directory listing, but at a guess this should work...

```
# wsgi.py
from app import create_app()
application = create_app()
```

In the guicorn command:

```
wsgi:application
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my command was actually correct.  The problem was in my version of Docker Toolbox and VM. Once update Vm and docker toolbox everything works fine